# java script alert a message when user click on window

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on a php site.I want to use java script code for alert message when user click on anywhere in window.i am using window.onclick=function name()

```
function function name()
{
alert('message');

}
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the click handler wrong, try

```
window.onclick = name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`function function name()` this line making issue.  you declared function as twice. for this javascript is breaking.

use like this

```
function name()
{
 alert('sds');
}
```

then assign function to the click handler like this.

```
window.onclick = name;
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
function name()
{
alert('message');

}
```

and then you need to use `window.onclick='name()';`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.onclick = clickMe;    
function clickMe()
    {
        alert("clickMe");
    }
```

window.onclick did not work when tested in IE8. So apparently the bottom line is that document.onclick is the preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.onclick = yourfunction() {}`